# Regex to disregard certain characters in an email

Tags: regex, email, portia

I need your help with extracting correct email with a regular expression.
Here is a raw HTML:

```
  </a>
  <script>
      var XutJPVbvZ = 'sales@some##thing.com';
      var XutJPVbvZ = XutJPVbvZ.split('#');
      document.getElementById('XutJPVbvZ').innerHTML = 
           XutJPVbvZ[0]+XutJPVbvZ[2]+XutJPVbvZ[1]; 
      document.getElementById('XutJPVbvZ').href = 
           'mailto:'+XutJPVbvZ[0]+XutJPVbvZ[2]+XutJPVbvZ[1];
  </script>
</div>
```

I match an email with this expression:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+
```

What I get is this: sales@some##thing.com

How to make regex return an email without two **#** special characters in the middle of this email address?

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to still match the email but strip out the '#' chars, or only match valid emails?

Comment: Yep, I want to match the email but to to strip out the '#' chars

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to do a search and replace on the string after matching with the regex... unless you want to play around with matching groups (even then you still need post-processing to put the groups back together)

Comment: @swalladge I can't do that because this is scraped html... I'm exporting it in csv so maybe I can do it here after, but it would be great if I can do it with the expression while scrapping...

Comment: It might help if you detailed what tools you are using in your question. :)

Comment: I want to link this meta QA: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329321/unethical-possibly-illegal-assistance

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully get your question but can answer anyway: use regex replace with capturing groups like shown in the Javascript code below:

```js
const regex = /([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+)\#\#([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+)/gm;
const str = `sales@some##thing.com`;
const subst = `$1@$2$3$4`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```